# Solr delete statement error

Tags: curl, solr

I'm trying out solr...I get the following error when trying a delete query:

```
 curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data-binary '<delete><id>SP2514N</id></delete>'
```

the error is:

```
Error 400 missing content stream  
Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason: missing content stream
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answer seems correct but doesn't explain the reason.
You only need to change the content type you're using to `text/xml`, otherwise curl uses the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` with the `--data-binary` option (or `-d`).

You should use the following command:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' http://localhost:8983/solr/update --data-binary '<delete><id>SP2514N</id></delete>'
```

You might want to add the `commit=true` parameter to the url to immediately issue a commit, otherwise you'll still see the document you wanted to delete (until the next commit).

You can also pass the xml directly within the url [via GET](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Updating_via_GET) like suggested in the other answer, using the `stream.body` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use : -

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=<delete><query>id:SP2514N</query></delete>&commit=true
```